Handling classes inheriting the same base class in a mvvm structure
I have setup an MVVM Structure in a .NET MAUI application.
My models are structured like this:
public partial class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bird : Animal
    {
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }

public class Fish : Animal
    {
        public int FinCount { get; set; }
    }

Now I have one view that looks at a viewmodel containing a List<Animals>
and shows it to the user. Now when the user clicks on a item in the list,
the application calls a Command that changes the view to a "DetailView" and
passes the clicked element to the detail view.
The detail viewmodel has an [ObservableProperty] Animal detailedAnimal.
Is it possible to distinguish between the Bird and the Fish class in the XAML?
Depending on what kind of animal it is, I want the view to show different control elements.
This is currently realized by setting an observable property when applying the query attribute from the list view. depending on that, I set different elements visible.
I dont want to check the class and move its specific properties to seperate observable properties to then display in the detail view.
But is there a way in the XAML of the detail view to address the properties of the different kind of objects that can be in this list or is it better to make a seperate view and viewmodel for every class that inherits Animal, and call the correct viewmodel when I click the element in the list?
Thanks!

you could use a DataTemplateSelector

In WPF you would define a DataTemplate for each Animal subclass with no  {x:Key} but a DataType. Then the right template would be chosen automatically, But cold be it don't work in Maui

DataTemplateSelector , Converter, or Trigger.
https://chat.openai.com/share/8937d06b-9b76-4952-b3bd-053e0cde0eb7

If I were you, I would just check on runtime the type of data that i am receiving and based on that, assign the right view

As Jason suggested, you can use DataTemplateSelector.
Here's the sample code that you can refer to:
public abstract class Animal
{
        public enum Types { Bird, Fish }
        public abstract Types Type { get; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bird : Animal
{
        public override Types Type => Types.Bird;
        public string Color { get; set; }
}

public class Fish : Animal
{
        public override Types Type => Types.Fish;
        public int FinCount { get; set; }
}

public class AnimalDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
        public DataTemplate Bird { get; set; }

        public DataTemplate Fish { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            var obj = (Animal)item;

            if (obj.Type == Animal.Types.Bird)
            {
                return Bird;
            }
            else
            {
                return Fish;
            }
        }
}


